# access eggs in python?

Tags: python, egg

Is there any way to call an installed python egg from python code? I need to cal a sphinx documentation
generator from within a python code, and currently i'm doing it like this:

`os.system( "sphinx-build.exe -b html c:\\src c:\\dst" )`

This works, but requires some additional configuration: 'scripts' folder
inside a python installation folder need to be added to a system PATH
( i'm on Windows ). Is it any better, native way to call an installed python
egg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically, you want to use Sphinx as a library?

Here is what `sphinx-build` does:

```
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

load_entry_point('Sphinx==0.5.1', 'console_scripts', 'sphinx-build')()
```

Looking at `entry-points.txt` in the EGG-INFO directory, notice that the sphinx-build entry point is the `sphinx.main` function (located in `__init__.py`).

Have a look at that and duplicate what it does, and you can use sphinx as a library. I have not looked at the code in detail, but it seems that the bulk of the `sphinx-build`-command is done by the `build` method on a `Sphinx` object.

In your code, you would have to do something like:

```
from sphinx.application import Sphinx
s = Sphinx(...)
s.build(...)
```

You need to have a look at the Sphinx source code to figure out the parameters to `Sphinx.__init__()` and `Sphinx.build()`

Answer (score 1):

Adding the egg to PYTHONPATH or to sys.path will allow you to access the modules and packages within.

Comment: -1: No reference to the documentation: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html